# How can I define different font face when using babel?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, babel

This command can be used to specify different font faces using fontspec package:

```
\setmainfont{texgyretermes-regular}[
  Extension      = .otf ,
  BoldFont       = texgyretermes-bold,
  ItalicFont     = texgyretermes-italic,
  BoldItalicFont = texgyretermes-bolditalic
]
```

My RTL text crashed when I tried to use \setmainfont command like the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\babelprovide[import, main]{persian}
\setmainfont{Amiri}
\begin{document}
  این یک متن نمونه است\\
  this is a sample text.
\end{document}
```

I typically use the following format for writing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{persian}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
%%how can i set another font for typesetting bold-face?
\begin{document}
  این یک متن 
  \textbf{نمونه}
  است.
\end{document}
```

Sometimes the font I use does not have different font face.

Is it possible to use a command for \babelfont without using fontspec to select different font face for a font from among the system's font?
Is there a way for LaTeX to automate create font face such as bold and italic for a font that it does not have?

i use LuaLaTeX engine.

sorry for my english. thanks for your help.

Comment: \babelfont use fontspec. And for me it iworks fine, I get bold and slanted. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k61h.png. Is your tex system up-to-date? Show the log-file of your babelfont example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for your help. I did not know that. I wanted to use a similar font from another family, for example with this command `\babelfont{rm}{behdad}[BoldItalicFont ={Amiri}]` for a font that does not have bold face But now I understand that i can do this with the command `\babelfont{rm}[AutoFakeBold=1.5]{behdad}` and Parts of the text that font need to be changed can also be done by changing the font family from rm to sf and other. now my problem solved